# extracting row from dataframe as a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in python. When i print the dataframe, I get this -

> audspec_lengthL1norm_sma_range  ...  mfcc_sma_de[14]_stddevFallingSlope
> file                                               start  end                                                     ...
> /home/sandeep/Documents/trials/au... 0 days 0 days 00:00:00.500000                        0.181606  ...                           25.396582
>
> [1 rows x 6373 columns]

since it is a single row dataframe, I want to extract that row of dimension 6373 and put it in a list. Please suggest how to do this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just extract your row (as `Series`) and convert it [`tolist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html).

```py
df.iloc[0].tolist()
```